# How to appear and disappear an image with GestureDetector in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I'm making a language learning app that has a deferent language I want the user when chose a language a checkbox image appear in the left on the Container

but I don't know how to do it , I trying to do it with a GestureDetector  but it didn't work (when I select one language all languages been selected how can I solve this problem)

this is how it look like
[image]

this is my code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Language List..
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: AppColor.mainColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 4,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: const Offset(0, 0),
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      color: Colors.white),
//------------------------------------------------
// list inputs
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
//------------------------------------------------
// list title
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                        child: Text(
                          'My Language',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          style:
                              AppFont.smallText.copyWith(color: Colors.orange),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const appDivider(),
//------------------------------------------------
// list languages
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image: Image.asset('images/usa.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'English - اريد تعلم الانجليزية'),
                      const appDivider(),
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image: Image.asset('images/china.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'Chinese - اريد تعلم الصينية'),
                      const appDivider(),
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image: Image.asset('images/spain.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'Spanish - اريد تعلم الاسبانية'),
                      const appDivider(),
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image: Image.asset('images/germany.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'German - اريد تعلم الامانية'),
                      const appDivider(),
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image: Image.asset('images/turkey.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'Turkish - اريد تعلم التركية'),
                      const appDivider(),
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image: Image.asset('images/france.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'French - اريد تعلم الفرنسية'),
                      const appDivider(),
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image: Image.asset('images/russian.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'Russian - اريد تعلم الروسية'),
                      const appDivider(),
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image: Image.asset('images/japan.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'Japanese - اريد تعلم اليابانية'),
                      const appDivider(),
                      LanguageSlector(
                          image:
                              Image.asset('images/saudi-arabia.png', scale: 3),
                          name: 'Arabic - اريد تعلم العربية'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Can you include where you are using OnTap method and how you are selecting item

Comment: what do you mean by `checkbox image`?

Answer (score 0):

put languages in the list and loop on it to choose any one by index